# actionCommand in Swing Action seems to be dependent of I18N

Tags: java, swing, action

Here on Stack Overflow I read a lot about using Swing Actions rather than ActionListeners, so I started to use them within the application's menu.

Everything worked out nice until I introduces I18N, only to find out that the actionCommand of the MenuItem changes accordingly to the language.

Here is what I do:

```
class ExitAction extends AbstractAction {
    public void init() {
        putValue(Action.NAME, messageSource.getMessage("app.gui.action.exitApplication"));
    }
}
```

My guess is, that I did understand something wrong and this is not the way to do what I want to do.

Can you please help me?

Comment: what do you have in `ACTION_COMMAND_KEY` ?

Comment: @nachokk I haven't set it explicitly. Should I?

Comment: I don't understand your problem,  your title and what you write, what is wrong?

Comment: @nachokk I use `putValue(Action.NAME, "Exit");` in the Action. After changing the String, lets say, to the German "Beenden" the actionCommand in the ActionEvent is as well "Beenden". So if I change the label I have to change the place where I handle the action.

Comment: @hannes I don't understand why you should even care about the ActionCommand, Actiion is its own ActionListener, so when actionPerformed is called it, you're gurenteed association, this is the point of Action. Hey are self contained units of work

Comment: @MadProgrammer So my first guess was right: I did understand something not correctly in the concept of Actions. To be clear: It is good practice to implement an Action class for any action needed in an application?

Comment: Personally, I prefer Action, simply because they are self contained, Meaning it's very easy to apply to different parts of the application, menus, buttons, key bindings, they are self configuring, so if I apply it to menu item or button, they look the same. It removes the need for multi level if statements, making the code cleaner and easier to read. So IMHO, yes it's peferred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things...

Firstly, `NAME` affects the text of button, but if not specified, will also set the actionCommand. Property. Instead I think you're after the `ACTION_COMMAND_KEY` property

Secondly, there should actually be little need for it, as the `Action` is self contained, hat is, it is it's own `ActionListener`, so when `actionPerformed` is called on your `Action`, you are guaranteed the association

Comment: @nachokk Thanks, was typing it out on my iPad 1...wasn't very "easy" :P